# High disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [...], shards will be relocated away from this node

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, search-guard

I'm running Elasicsearch (`floragunncom/sg-elasticsearch:7.0.1-oss-35.0.0`) on kubernetes cluster(v1.18 - kind).

I've assigned each Elasticsearch data node (ie. pod) with `200Mi` of PVC as storage. But when the elasticseach cluster(3 master, 3 data, 2 ingest) is up, it is showing the following warning message:

> {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-07-20T06:27:14,354+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor", "cluster.name": "topology-es", "node.name": "master-topology-es-1", "cluster.uuid": "U0Yf6tiJSHC57R_QHa2qiw", "node.id": "tDet2llLQaydoxfYT4TcpQ",  "message": "high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [C-TUE5_cR1ihqrhThpWnsg][data-topology-es-1][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 5.5gb[7%], shards will be relocated away from this node"  }

- Where is this `5.5gb[7%]` coming from?

I aslo checked the shard's status:

```sh
$ curl -XGET "https://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?h=index,shard,prirep,state,unassigned.reason" -u "admin:XXXXX" --insecure
searchguard 0 p STARTED    
searchguard 0 r UNASSIGNED REPLICA_ADDED
searchguard 0 r UNASSIGNED REPLICA_ADDED
```

- If `200Mi` is not enough, then how comes the primary shard is successfully assigned in `data-node-0` but the replicas are not in `data-node-1` and `data-node-2` respectively?

Update:

```sh
$ curl -XGET "https://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/fs?pretty" -u "admin:XXXX" --insecure
{
  "_nodes" : {
    "total" : 8,
    "successful" : 8,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "cluster_name" : "topology-es",
  "nodes" : {
    "jYkduRCmQ2GEHMn2DeBrxg" : {
      "timestamp" : 1595231421976,
      "name" : "data-topology-es-0",
      "transport_address" : "10.244.0.59:9300",
      "host" : "10.244.0.59",
      "ip" : "10.244.0.59:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "data"
      ],
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1595231421989,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
          "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
            "mount" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda3)",
            "type" : "ext4",
            "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
            "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
          }
        ],
        "io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
            {
              "device_name" : "sda3",
              "operations" : 77306,
              "read_operations" : 7745,
              "write_operations" : 69561,
              "read_kilobytes" : 230532,
              "write_kilobytes" : 500284
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 77306,
            "read_operations" : 7745,
            "write_operations" : 69561,
            "read_kilobytes" : 230532,
            "write_kilobytes" : 500284
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "N7ql_AneQoa6w8yvgBhYZg" : {
      "timestamp" : 1595231421977,
      "name" : "client-topology-es-0",
      "transport_address" : "10.244.0.49:9300",
      "host" : "10.244.0.49",
      "ip" : "10.244.0.49:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "ingest"
      ],
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1595231421981,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
          "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
            "mount" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda3)",
            "type" : "ext4",
            "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
            "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
          }
        ],
        "io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
            {
              "device_name" : "sda3",
              "operations" : 84052,
              "read_operations" : 7853,
              "write_operations" : 76199,
              "read_kilobytes" : 231804,
              "write_kilobytes" : 565340
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 84052,
            "read_operations" : 7853,
            "write_operations" : 76199,
            "read_kilobytes" : 231804,
            "write_kilobytes" : 565340
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "gse01W_XR7qKvZPHPq7n7g" : {
      "timestamp" : 1595231421984,
      "name" : "master-topology-es-2",
      "transport_address" : "10.244.0.57:9300",
      "host" : "10.244.0.57",
      "ip" : "10.244.0.57:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "master"
      ],
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1595231421993,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
          "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
            "mount" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda3)",
            "type" : "ext4",
            "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
            "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
          }
        ],
        "io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
            {
              "device_name" : "sda3",
              "operations" : 77627,
              "read_operations" : 7747,
              "write_operations" : 69880,
              "read_kilobytes" : 230560,
              "write_kilobytes" : 504608
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 77627,
            "read_operations" : 7747,
            "write_operations" : 69880,
            "read_kilobytes" : 230560,
            "write_kilobytes" : 504608
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "bBNEuz2pSkWeOUmDIowEDQ" : {
      "timestamp" : 1595231421991,
      "name" : "client-topology-es-1",
      "transport_address" : "10.244.0.51:9300",
      "host" : "10.244.0.51",
      "ip" : "10.244.0.51:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "ingest"
      ],
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1595231421995,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
          "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
            "mount" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda3)",
            "type" : "ext4",
            "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
            "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
          }
        ],
        "io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
            {
              "device_name" : "sda3",
              "operations" : 82173,
              "read_operations" : 7788,
              "write_operations" : 74385,
              "read_kilobytes" : 231144,
              "write_kilobytes" : 546544
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 82173,
            "read_operations" : 7788,
            "write_operations" : 74385,
            "read_kilobytes" : 231144,
            "write_kilobytes" : 546544
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "-hwsv3rqQeSVdfOsKqzrwA" : {
      "timestamp" : 1595231422013,
      "name" : "master-topology-es-0",
      "transport_address" : "10.244.0.53:9300",
      "host" : "10.244.0.53",
      "ip" : "10.244.0.53:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "master"
      ],
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1595231422080,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
          "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
            "mount" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda3)",
            "type" : "ext4",
            "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
            "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
          }
        ],
        "io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
            {
              "device_name" : "sda3",
              "operations" : 79542,
              "read_operations" : 7762,
              "write_operations" : 71780,
              "read_kilobytes" : 230792,
              "write_kilobytes" : 521656
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 79542,
            "read_operations" : 7762,
            "write_operations" : 71780,
            "read_kilobytes" : 230792,
            "write_kilobytes" : 521656
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "C-TUE5_cR1ihqrhThpWnsg" : {
      "timestamp" : 1595231421984,
      "name" : "data-topology-es-1",
      "transport_address" : "10.244.0.61:9300",
      "host" : "10.244.0.61",
      "ip" : "10.244.0.61:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "data"
      ],
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1595231422003,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
          "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
            "mount" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda3)",
            "type" : "ext4",
            "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
            "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
          }
        ],
        "io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
            {
              "device_name" : "sda3",
              "operations" : 77169,
              "read_operations" : 7736,
              "write_operations" : 69433,
              "read_kilobytes" : 230396,
              "write_kilobytes" : 498544
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 77169,
            "read_operations" : 7736,
            "write_operations" : 69433,
            "read_kilobytes" : 230396,
            "write_kilobytes" : 498544
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "zlL7F5kRTLWWogzffZXomA" : {
      "timestamp" : 1595231422000,
      "name" : "data-topology-es-2",
      "transport_address" : "10.244.0.63:9300",
      "host" : "10.244.0.63",
      "ip" : "10.244.0.63:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "data"
      ],
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1595231422001,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
          "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
            "mount" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda3)",
            "type" : "ext4",
            "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
            "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
          }
        ],
        "io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
            {
              "device_name" : "sda3",
              "operations" : 77048,
              "read_operations" : 7736,
              "write_operations" : 69312,
              "read_kilobytes" : 230396,
              "write_kilobytes" : 496864
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 77048,
            "read_operations" : 7736,
            "write_operations" : 69312,
            "read_kilobytes" : 230396,
            "write_kilobytes" : 496864
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "tDet2llLQaydoxfYT4TcpQ" : {
      "timestamp" : 1595231421993,
      "name" : "master-topology-es-1",
      "transport_address" : "10.244.0.55:9300",
      "host" : "10.244.0.55",
      "ip" : "10.244.0.55:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "master"
      ],
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1595231422020,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
          "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
            "mount" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda3)",
            "type" : "ext4",
            "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
            "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
          }
        ],
        "io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
            {
              "device_name" : "sda3",
              "operations" : 77766,
              "read_operations" : 7748,
              "write_operations" : 70018,
              "read_kilobytes" : 230576,
              "write_kilobytes" : 505892
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 77766,
            "read_operations" : 7748,
            "write_operations" : 70018,
            "read_kilobytes" : 230576,
            "write_kilobytes" : 505892
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you run this `GET _nodes/stats/fs` ?

Comment: @Val, updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @opsterelasticsearchninja, Thank you so much for your answer. It was helpful. Hence I upvoted it. But It didn’t solve my problem. I added the reason in another answer.

Comment: @KamolHasan oh ok, thanks, glad i was helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is filesystem statistics for the master node `C-TUE5_cR1ihqrhThpWnsg` taken from the `_nodes/stats` output:

```
    "total" : {
      "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416,
      "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
      "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
    },
```

As you can see 5917450240 / 84054204416 = ~7%, so the storage space on that node is 93% full, hence why you're getting that warning.

Comment: Thanks, so this independent of how much storage (here `200Mi`) is assigned to a pod via PVC?

Comment: Here the data is stored on sda3 which has apparently 85GB of storage space. Also, judging by the numbers, it seems that all your nodes share the same disk

Answer (score 1):

So, here is my problem: I've assigned storage of `200Mi` to each Elasticsearch data node via PVC. When I checked the `_nodes/stats`:

```
 "total" : {
      "total_in_bytes" : 84054204416, <-- ~84Gi
      "free_in_bytes" : 10231291904,
      "available_in_bytes" : 5917450240
    },
```

So, the expected value should be `200Mi` instead of `~84Gi`.

**Explanation:**

Since I'm in [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) cluster. The default storage is provisioned by `hostpath` and we get a directory mounted from the host, not a separate file system.

And `kind` uses [rancher/local-path-provisioner](https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner), and the current limitation of using it are:

```
- No support for the volume capacity limit currently.
    - The capacity limit will be ignored for now.
```

That's why I was getting `~84Gi` (host) instead of `200Mi` (assigned via PVC).